# Poco WebSocket throwing Malformed url exception. Why?

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I'm writing a server-side WebSocket, using Poco and c++. Right now I'm trying to accept an HTTP request to upgrade to a WebSocket. When I test it, it throws an error saying the request was malformed. So I opened it up in gdb, and printed out the request and found it was indeed not a regular WebSocket upgrade request. Here's the GDB output.

```
(gdb) x/518xb buf
0x7fffffffb920: 0x16    0x03    0x01    0x02    0x00    0x01    0x00    0x01
0x7fffffffb928: 0xfc    0x03    0x03    0x8c    0x36    0x36    0x84    0x63
0x7fffffffb930: 0x9b    0x72    0x68    0x55    0xe2    0xad    0x61    0x63
0x7fffffffb938: 0xd8    0x05    0x94    0x69    0x6a    0x2e    0xf5    0x09
0x7fffffffb940: 0xac    0x10    0xc5    0xe8    0x6b    0x93    0x87    0x8f
0x7fffffffb948: 0x34    0xf6    0x4e    0x20    0xe6    0x1c    0x52    0xd6
0x7fffffffb950: 0x39    0xd4    0x46    0xae    0x03    0xe5    0x92    0xf3
0x7fffffffb958: 0x56    0x2e    0x33    0xc7    0x30    0x9a    0xc8    0xbd
0x7fffffffb960: 0xc6    0x72    0x82    0x47    0x2f    0x9a    0x2d    0xb4
0x7fffffffb968: 0x43    0x77    0x6d    0xbb    0x00    0x24    0x13    0x01
0x7fffffffb970: 0x13    0x03    0x13    0x02    0xc0    0x2b    0xc0    0x2f
0x7fffffffb978: 0xcc    0xa9    0xcc    0xa8    0xc0    0x2c    0xc0    0x30
0x7fffffffb980: 0xc0    0x0a    0xc0    0x09    0xc0    0x13    0xc0    0x14
0x7fffffffb988: 0x00    0x33    0x00    0x39    0x00    0x2f    0x00    0x35
0x7fffffffb990: 0x00    0x0a    0x01    0x00    0x01    0x8f    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffb998: 0x00    0x0e    0x00    0x0c    0x00    0x00    0x09    0x6c
0x7fffffffb9a0: 0x6f    0x63    0x61    0x6c    0x68    0x6f    0x73    0x74
0x7fffffffb9a8: 0x00    0x17    0x00    0x00    0xff    0x01    0x00    0x01
0x7fffffffb9b0: 0x00    0x00    0x0a    0x00    0x0e    0x00    0x0c    0x00
0x7fffffffb9b8: 0x1d    0x00    0x17    0x00    0x18    0x00    0x19    0x01
0x7fffffffb9c0: 0x00    0x01    0x01    0x00    0x0b    0x00    0x02    0x01
0x7fffffffb9c8: 0x00    0x00    0x23    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x10    0x00
0x7fffffffb9d0: 0x0e    0x00    0x0c    0x02    0x68    0x32    0x08    0x68
```

Just a quick look at the hex shows it's not regular chars. There's a lot of non alpha-numeric chars. But when I inspect the network activity in the browser, it shows the text of the request, plain as day. So why are the bytes my program is receiving different than the ones the browser claims to be sending?

Server side (c++) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponseImpl.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequestImpl.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerConnection.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerSession.h"

#define PORT (unsigned short) 3000
#define MAX_BYTES 9999
int main()
{
        Poco::Net::ServerSocket x(PORT);
        Poco::Timespan timeout(25000000);
        char buf[MAX_BYTES];
        memset(buf,0,MAX_BYTES);
        if (x.poll(timeout, 1)) {
                Poco::Net::StreamSocket ss = x.acceptConnection();
                int i = ss.receiveBytes(buf, MAX_BYTES);
                printf("received %d bytes, %s\n", i, buf);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Client side (javascript):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    webSoc = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:3000");
    webSoc.onopen = function (event) {
        $("#c").click(function () {
            webSoc.send("Hello, World!\n");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: All that cruft you see is most likely HTTP protocol related which you don't address with your server side code in any way. Specifically, why a `WebSocket()` on the client and a `ServerSocket()` on the server - rather than a [`WebSocket()`](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.WebSocket.html) on the server which utilizes an `HTTPRequestHandler`? Really out of my league here though.

Comment: Websockets (if I understand right) can only be made by upgrading from HTTP. The server Socket is to create an HTTP socket, which will then create the WebSocket. I'm out of my league too, this is just what I understand from reading through poco documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re connecting through `wss` which means the connection will be encrypted using SSL or TLS. These begin with a handshake, which is the first 0x16 byte. Next is encryption type, 0x03 0x01 (TLS 1.0), then length 2 bytes. Then 0x01 meaning client hello and so on. So this is completely normal.

If you want to have a plain HTTP session use `ws` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I got it off by literally one character. I changed `"wss://localhost:3000"` to `"ws://localhost:3000"`

`wss` stands for WebSocket Secure. So, my websocket was encrypting the data before it sent. The serverside socket was trying to interpret it as though it were not encrypted, and rightly discovering it's malformed for an unencrypted socket.